# MySQL indexing on max and min columns with where clause

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have table which can be created by

```
CREATE TABLE 
`1m_candles` (`exchange_name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
              `market_name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
              `open` decimal(20,8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
              `high` decimal(20,8) unsigned NOT NULL,
              `low` decimal(20,8) unsigned NOT NULL,
              `close` decimal(20,8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
              `time` datetime NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`exchange_name`,`market_name`,`time`),
              KEY `make_candles` (`exchange_name`, `market_name`, `time`, `high`, `low`)
             ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and I'm using a query like this below a lot.

```
SELECT MAX(`high`), MIN(`low`) 
FROM `1mi_candles` 
WHERE exchange_name = 'BINANCE' 
  AND market_name = 'ADABTC' 
  AND `time` >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' 
  AND `time` < '2020-01-03 00:00:00'
```

I'm using primary key for unique row (exchange_name, market_name and time).

Does my indexing really work? Is that the correct way which I've created the keys?

Comment: I think that `make_candles` index is used. See query EXPLAIN. PS. Including a datetime into the primary index is a highly questionable activity...

Comment: I think there is no other way to achieve this unique value in table for (exchange_name, market_name and time). Do you have a suggestion for this?

Comment: Of course. Use synthetic PK and UNIQUE bvy this expression. Or prove (to yourself primarily) that a natural key is necessary.

Comment: Sorry but I  don't get "Use synthetic PK and UNIQUE bvy this expression." part of your reply. Can you give me more detail on it or a link which explains this concept?

Comment: Synthetic PK == AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Doesn't a "candle" show 4 values?  Open, close, high, low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PRIMARY KEY` is virtually the best possible.  The added `KEY` does not add enough to the situation to be worth having.

Having an `AUTO_INCREMENT` would be wasteful, since you have a perfectly good 'natural' primary key.

In *this* application, it is fine to have a `DATETIME` in a unique (or primary) key.  This, however, assumes you never have two readings for a ticker at the same *second*.  If you are capturing *every* trade, this needs to be readdressed.

If the table will have lots of tickers over lots of days, the table will be quite big.  If you get concerned about the table size, consider:

- The secondary index can be dropped (as mentioned above).
- `decimal(20,8)` seems like overkill.  It occupies 10 bytes.
- The exchange and market_name could be normalized into another table, replacing them by a single 3-byte `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`.

The table name is "make_candles".  Does this mean you will be graphing "candles"?  That means you need the high, low, open, and close for each unit of time for each ticker.  If that involves collecting a thousand rows to make *each* candle, then we should talk about "summary tables" to make the fetching of *sufficient* information for each candle.  It is very easy to summarize and roll-up high, low, open, and close for, say, each day into, say, weekly or monthly high, low, open, and close.

Comment: `The secondary index can be dropped (as mentioned above).`

Is my secondary index useful in MAX and MIN columns?

Comment: @rasputin - Technically, yes.  But it is not practical -- That index is only 2 columns shy if having all the columns.  That is, the speed of using the index would be only slightly faster than simply using the data's BTree.  And there is some cost of having an "unnecessary" index.  My suggestions for shrinking the datatypes would probably provide more benefit.